# How do I know if my Xeon Processor supports hardware virtualisation?

Tags: virtualization, central-processing-unit, xeon

I've been scouring the net (mainly the wikipaedia lists and intel's site. I even pulled out the datasheet for my processor) but I can't seem to answer this question.

**Does my Xeon support hardware virtualisation?**

The processor in question is a:

"Nocona" (standard-voltage, 90 nm) 2800MHz. Other details can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Nocona.22_.28standard-voltage.2C_90_nm.29

I'm pretty sure the answer is no as it's a pretty old server but I can't find a single place which has a definitive yes/no answer so I'm still looking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no Intel-VT hardware in those chips sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Intel has a site for detailed processor specifications, which is pretty hard to find. I searched for a few weeks.

The site is located [here](http://ark.intel.com/ProductCollection.aspx?familyID=594). This is the top page for xeons.

The site might come in handy if You might be searching for a replacement processor.

The cpu comparison worked best for me after I marked every processor for comparison and pasted the resulting html table into an openoffice spreadsheet.

Comment: You're welcome. I researched xeons for my small startup. What do You need those for.